# Third party project not in GIT - New version - Keep my changes

Tags: git, conflict

I have bought (licenced) some code from Codecanyon that is not maintained in GIT.
I have now made quite a few changes to it (using GIT).
Pretty soon the authors of the original code will release a new version.
I will want to incorporate their changes without losing my own.
I would therefore like to load their code and get GIT to point out conflicts so that I may be able to (hopefully) incorporate the new code into mine.
Can anyone recommend a safe way of achieving this please?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have, in your local repo, a commit with the first version of their code :

```
$ git log --graph --oneline
1234ee * (HEAD -> master) my latest changes 
1234dd * added a feature
  ...
1234aa * a commit, with the initial version of the product's code
  ...
```

You can :

- create a branch that starts on that commit :

```
git checkout -b upstream 1234aa
```

- update the code with the new version :

```
# to be thorough : you should delete files which existed in the first version,
# and do not exist in the new version
git rm -- [list all files of original archive]

# for example, here is one way to drop all versioned files :
git rm -- "*"

# extract the files from the new version :
tar -xzf newversion.tgz

# add and commit :
git add .
git commit -m "new version"
```

- you can now merge `upstream` in your local branch :

```
git checkout master
git merge upstream
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not so good to mix git with non-git projects and maybe this is opinion based, but this is what I would do:

1. Create a git repo, put your 3rd party code in it and do your first commit (this will be your `master`or `main` branch as you whish to call it.
2. Create a new branch `next` (you choose tha name)
3. Do your modifications on this branch, commit them regularly and merge them to `master` when they work properly.
4. When your 3rd party project has a new release, **make sure** all your modifications are in your `master`, then create a branch `thirdParty` and replace its content with the new release (this is where it gets ugly).
5. Commit this change.
6. Then you have two options a) Merge `thirdParty` with `master` or b) `master` with `thirdParty`. This can be very messy taking in count that their modifications must be huge, so I'd choose b).
7. Git will print all the conflicts and you will solve them :)